# Get the parent key by matching the value using Regular Expression

Tags: python, json, regex, dictionary

Consider the below json object, Here I need to take the parent key by matching the value using regular expression.

```
{
    "PRODUCT": {
        "attribs": {
            "U1": {
                "name": "^U.*1$"
            },
            "U2": {
                "name": "^U.*2$"
            },
            "U3": {
                "name": "^U.*3$"
            },
            "U4": {
                "name": "^U.*4$"
            },
            "U5": {
                "name": "^U.*5$"
            },
            "P1": {
                "name": "^P.*1$"
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

I will be passing a String like this "U10001", It should return the key(U1) by matching the regular expression(^U.*1$).

If I am passing a String like this "P200001", It should return the key(P1) by matching the regular expression(^P.*1$).

I am looking for some help regarding the same, Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `startswith('U')` might help you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are getting your JSON, but you added python as a tag so I'm assuming at somepoint you will have it stored as a string in your code.

First decode the string into a python dict.

```
import json
my_dict = json.loads(my_json)["PRODUCT"]["attribs"]
```

If the JSON is formatted as above you should get a dict with keys as your U1, U2, etc.

Now you can use `filter` in python to apply your regular expression logic, and `re` to do the actual matching.

```
import re
test_string = "U10001"
def re_filter(item):
   return re.match(item[1]["name"], test_string)

result = filter(re_filter, my_dict.items())

# Just get the matching attribute names
print [i[0] for i in result]
```

I haven't ran the code so it might need some syntax fixing, but this should give you the general idea. Of course you will need to make it more generic to allow multiple products.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import re
my_dict = {...}


def get_key(dict_, test):
    return next(k for k, v in dict_.items() if re.match(v['name'], test))

test = "U10001"
result = get_key(my_dict['PRODUCT']['attribs'], test))
print(result)  # U1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate on what you exactly want to design? Here's a quick way to return the desired key.

```
import re
def getKey(string):
    return re.search('^(.\d)\d+', string).group(1)
```

If you want to loop over the whole json, then load it into dictionary and then loop over the "PRODUCT"->"attribs" dictionary to get required key-

```
import json, re
f = open('../file/path/here')
d = json.loads(f.read())
patents = d['PRODUCT']['attribs']

for key,val in patent_attribute.items():
    patent_group =  re.search('^(.\d)\d+', val['name']).group(1) #returns U1 U2,U3,.. or P1,P2,P3,..
    #do whatever with patent_group(U1/P1 etc)
```